# Break line of text in d3 Sankey Diagram labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I break the line of my text for each of my d3 node labels. I've seen a version of this applied to a d3 chart but it is not working quite correctly. How can I do this with a label for a node in a sankey diagram?

Comment: What code are you using to apply labels now? Showing that will make it easier to provide an answer that has applicable context.

Answer (score -1):

Adding a `\n` to the string passed to the text of a label will cause a line break. This can be seen in d.name + '\n' + formatVote(d.value)` which when passed d.name of "name" and d.value of 4 which gets formatted to "4 votes":

> name
>   4 votes

```js
.text(function (d: any) {
    return d.name + '\n' + formatVote(d.value);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't constitute an answer, and should really be only a comment.